# iOS: How do I swipe between views (using Swift)

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, swipe

I'm new to Swift and iOS development, and am looking how to set up a main view where I want swipe right for a second view or left for a third view. When I am in the second or the third view it should be possible to swipe back to the main view.
As the background is an image I don't want it to swipe together with the content. It should stay at the same position all the time. So I think I can not do it with a PageViewController because that one swipes between View Controllers where the background can not stay at the same position.

The things I want to swipe between are all three navagation structures (a tap bar, a springboard and a list)

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

This is not Swift specific. The same frameworks and APIs are available in both Swift and Objective-C.

You want a UIPageViewController. That controller manages an array of view controllers, and will either offer a page curl transition like iBooks, or a slide-to-the-side transition.

There is a sample project called PhotoScroller linked in the Xcode docs that illustrates how to use it, although it looks like it might not be available in the Xcode 6 help docs. A Google search on "PhotoScroller" finds it on Apple's developer site however.

The project is in Objective-C, but it shows how to set up a page view conotroller with a data source.